# Time Capsule Fileshare over internet with windows

Tags: windows, networking, router, remote-connection, time-capsule

I can access the hard disc from the time capsule over the internet with any mac computer. But it is not working with windows. Windows prompts the network security alert where I have to enter the username and password. But the correct username and password is always wrong. For example, if I enter the credentials Michael in the username field and qwerty123 in the password field on a mac, it connects. The same on windows and it says wrong credentials.

My setup is as follows:
A router is connected to the WAN. Because the IP changes every 24h, I setup a dyn DNS. The time capsule is connected to the router with a cable and is in bridge mode. Windows and OSX can access the hard disc in the LAN. The router makes a port forwarding to the time capsule.

Comment: are you able connect any windows computer using same credentials on your local network.

Comment: yes it works on the local network with the credentials

Comment: download http://gdriv.es/myfile/AirPortUtility5.6.1.zip . and try to edit workgroup make it same on windows and let me know if it helped .

Answer (score 0):

You just need to work out what "domain" Windows thinks the Time Capsule is on, this is often the net bios name of the device, and preface the user name with netbiosname\username.

Comment: What is a domain and where can I find the net bios name?